# The significance of Simpsons's joke about Bowzer

Tags: plot-explanation, the-simpsons

In the episode 6 of the Season 10, Abraham Simpson and family went to Woodstock Festival. While Hendrix is playing the US national anthem Abe show a message about someone named Bowzer.
[image]

**What's the joke behind this sign?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As explained on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSimpsons/comments/1i7rib/bowzer_for_president/cb1zt6h):

> Sha na na was a "faux retro" group that sang doo wop songs from the
>   50's (which is why Abe liked them). Bowzer was a popular member of the
>   group (the joke in the show was a goof, however, because Bowzer didn't
>   join the group until after their Woodstock performance in 1969).

[Jon "Bowzer" Bauman, as described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Bauman):

> Jon "Bowzer" Bauman (born September 14, 1947) is an American musician,
>   best known as a member of the band Sha Na Na, and game show host.
>   Bauman's popular Sha Na Na character, "Bowzer", was a gangly,
>   slender-armed greaser in a muscle shirt.

Answer (score 3):

Bowzer is a nickname for [Jon Bauman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Bauman), a member of the band "[Sha Na Na](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha_Na_Na)", who appeared at Woodstock.

> Conceived by George Leonard, then a graduate student in humanities, Sha Na Na began performing in 1969 at the height of the hippie counterculture, and achieved national fame after playing at the Woodstock Festival, where they preceded Jimi Hendrix. Their 90-second appearance in the Woodstock film brought the group national attention and helped spark a 1950s nostalgia craze that inspired similar groups in North America, as well as the Broadway musical Grease, the feature film American Graffiti and the TV show Happy Days.

Amusingly, Bauman wasn't actually a member of the band when they performed at Woodstock.